# hudson codenarc issue

Tags: groovy, build, hudson, codenarc

I am developing a grails application which has [codenarc](http://grails.org/plugin/codenarc) plugin. And also I am using hudson build tool. I am integrating the application with [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) build tool. In the hudson  I have configured violation plugin. But when I build the app I am getting following error.

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Cannot parse CodeNarcReport.xml
    at hudson.plugins.violations.parse.AbstractTypeParser.parse(AbstractTypeParser.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.doType(ViolationsCollector.java:189)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.invoke(ViolationsCollector.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsCollector.invoke(ViolationsCollector.java:27)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:757)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:739)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsPublisher.perform(ViolationsPublisher.java:74)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:601)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:579)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:156)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:548)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1386)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.plugins.violations.model.Violation.compareTo(Violation.java:192)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.model.Violation.compareTo(Violation.java:8)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.model.FullFileModel.addViolation(FullFileModel.java:24)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.types.codenarc.CodenarcParser.parseFileElement(CodenarcParser.java:90)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.types.codenarc.CodenarcParser.execute(CodenarcParser.java:47)
    at hudson.plugins.violations.parse.AbstractTypeParser.parse(AbstractTypeParser.java:59)
    ... 16 more
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Grails version : 1.3.7

Hudson version : 1.398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By updating violation plugin to 0.7.8 snapshot version fixed the issue. [Download link](http://ci.jenkins-ci.org/job/plugins_violations/lastBuild/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins%24violations/artifact/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins/violations/0.7.8-SNAPSHOT/violations.hpi)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend asking CodeNarc questions on the CodeNarc mailing list. 
Also, be aware the the Hudson/Jenkins plugin usually has an older version of CodeNarc bundled with it. It's not maintained by the CodeNarc team. I recommend sticking with the Grails plugin, which is maintained by the team.

Thanks, 
Hamlet (CodeNarc developer)